# disable dropdownlist on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have 2 dropdownlists populated from database:
what I want is to disable the second one on page load and when the value of the first one =="1".

here is my second dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="BName" DataValueField="BId"  
                  OnDataBound="DownList2_DataBound" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This what I tried to disable the dropdownlist2 (javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('DropDownList2').disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

Tried another thing in C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1")
    { 
        DropDownList2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I even tried this alone in page_load:

```
DropDownList2.Enabled = false;
```

The problem is it's disabled on SelectedIndexChanged for dropdownlist1 but not on page load! Is there's something missing in my code?

Comment: @rene I don't see a problem with (thanks)!
but thank you for letting me know the site rules :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement allow you to set the dropdown2 to disable at page load.

`$('#' + '<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>').attr('disabled',true);`

you can do this using Jquery simply as follow:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

      var isPostBack = '<%=IsPostBack%>';
        if (isPostBack == 'False' || $('#' + '<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').val() == '1') {
          //This statement allow you to set the dropdown2 to disable 
          $('#' + '<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', true);
      }
      else {
          $('#' + '<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', false);
      }
      $('#' + '<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').on("change", function () {
          //Your code here
          if ($('#' + '<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').val() == '1') {
                $('#' + '<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', true);
           }
           else {
               $('#' + '<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', false);
           }
        });
  });
```

Comment: your code works and disabled for me, but it keeps it disabled even I select another value from dropdownlist1

Comment: Have you confirmed that the DropDownList2 is disabled and enabled only by this code. Is there any code that making `DropDownList2` disable again?

Comment: Ok,I understand the actual issue. You need to remove the code you have write on selectedIndexChanged for dropdownlist1 and try my edited answer. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` is not equal to "1" on Page Load as I guess you'd be DataBinding it somehow, which would take effect afterwards.

Try adding a SelectedIndexChanged function for DropDownList1 and dis/enabling DropDownList2 here. You can put `Enabled="False"` in the markup for DropDownList2 to ensure it starts off Disabled.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I have already selected value is one on page load:
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Select Category</asp:ListItem>

Comment: Are you able to debug and step through the Page_Load() code? Use the Intermediate Window in Visual Studio to determine what the value of DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() is. You will also see if the next line is being executed.

Comment: yes I put break point and the value is 1 and enabled = false but I can't see it in my browser!!

Comment: Then could it be that the values are being changed elsewhere in the code? Or even client-side?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely that `document.getElementById('DropDownList2')` doesn't find your dropdown list. The `ID` for the list is a server-side value that doesn't necessarily translate to the client-side ID. If you set `ClientIDMode` for the control to `Static`, then the client ID will be `DropDownList2`. Another option is to access the `ClientID` property of the control when outputting your JavaScript (if it's inline):

```
document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
```

All that being said, even if that's the case, it'd be better to just start with `Enabled="False"` as @aaroncatlin suggests so you don't have to wait for the JavaScript to execute before it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

in ASP.NET the generated ID differs from the asp ID on the component, to access the element from Javascript you need to use <%=DropDownList2.ClientID%> the corresponding javascript will be something like this :

```
document.getElementById(<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>).disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The DropDownList would have a default selected index of -1 and a null value for selected value.  I usually check against the selected index, instead of by value.  For example,

```
if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex < 1){
    // assuming that index 0 holds your value of "1"
    DropDownList2.Enabled = false;
}
```

And @Jacob did rightly point out about you needing to get the proper ClientID for your JavaScript function.